# Best ru-en translation library for Python - that is not googletrans

Tags: python, translation

I realise that there are several language translation related questions on SO, but as far as I could tell my question hasn't been asked before.

*Background*
I have a project where I need to translate some snippets written in Russian to English. So far, I have used the [googletrans Python library](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/) to accomplish this. Since November googletrans [has had some issues](https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/issues/234), and I am looking into alternatives.

As far as I can tell, Google has worked to block googletrans to convert users to its paid google cloud translation API.

*So my question is...*
What are the best alternatives to googletrans? I would prefer one that

1. works reliably,
2. is free,
3. does not rely on Google Translate Ajax API (as this option does not seem to be reliable), and
4. works in Python2.7.

1)--4) are all nice to have rather than mandatory.

So far, I have been testing the Google Cloud Translation API, but it might be prohibitively expensive. Other libraries use other translation services, but there are literally dozens of them so I would love to hear your recommendations.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently launched [Libretranslate](https://libretranslate.com) would seem to suit my usage.

Api docs [here](https://libretranslate.com/docs/). Also runs offline, as per these [instructions](http://terokarvinen.com/2021/free-offline-ai-translate-for-english-russian-arabic-spanish-german/).